# How to set default save location for java program?

Tags: java, file, directory

I want to get the file path for the .jar file that is running. In Ubuntu at least the default save location is the user's home directory, is there any way to get the directory of the jar file so that I can save files there? I would like the solution to also work in windows if possible. Thanks.

Comment: That is just silly.  Don't go looking for the application directory, put extra stuff in `user.home`.

Answer (score 2):

To get the working directory the jar was launched from:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

This might not necessarily be where the jar is, though, since you can do `java -jar path/to/jar`. If you want the directory where the jar is located, try:

```
MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
```

This will give you the path to the jar file containing this class.

Comment: Note that neither of those would work as expected for a JWS app. or applet, and would also require an app. with all-permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current working directory like this:

```
String curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```